# MKMapView leaking from autorealease in main.m

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, mkmapview, instruments, core-location

I know from this forum that this is a known bug that has been reported to Apple, but I am concerned that the memory leak keeps increasing everytime I call the view.
[image]

the relevant code is

```
-(IBAction)getlocationgo:(id) sender{
    //NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
    //pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    self.locationManager=[[[CLLocationManager alloc]init]autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;


    //mapView.showsUserLocation =YES;
    //[pool release];


}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)aManager didFailWithError:(NSError*)anError
{
    switch([anError code])
    {
        case kCLErrorLocationUnknown: // location is currently unknown, but CL will keep trying
            break;

        case kCLErrorDenied: // CL access has been denied (eg, user declined location use)
            {UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Location Error"
                                  message:@"Please enable Location Services in the Settings menu"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
             AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

            [alert show];
            [alert release];}
            break;

        case kCLErrorNetwork: // general, network-related error
            {UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Location Error"
                               message:@"The Little Helper can't find you - please check your network connection or that you are not in airplane mode"
                               delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

            [alert show];
            [alert release];}
            break;
    }

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"thisruns");
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta =0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta =0.2;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = newLocation.coordinate;


    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    mapView.showsUserLocation =YES;
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;

    latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *newloc=longitude.text;
    NSLog(@"long%f", newloc);

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

the property's are with this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

and it is dealloced

```
mapView.delegate = nil;
[mapView release];
locationManager.delegate = nil;
[locationManager release];
```

I have been going back and forward with this for a few days now, any help or tips would be great.
Thank you

Edit One
 Trying to access locationManager in the app delegate, everything runs but there is no update to the location from the IBaction
This is the code in the IBaction and the result from the log is (null)

```
 LLHelperAppDelegate *appDelegate = (LLHelperAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    appDelegate.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    NSLog(@"%@", [appDelegate locationManager]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst as an Apple issue you won't be able to remove the leak entirely, you can definitely stop it from happening every time you trigger `getlocationgo`. Rather than constantly creating a `CLLocationManager`, just use a single `CLLocationManager` in your app's delegate (or create a singleton to support it). That way you'll only alloc/init a location manager once during your app's lifecycle, whereas currently you alloc/init one every time you reload that view / call the `getlocationgo` method.

Comment: Good point, I am not having any success accessing locationManager from the app delegate

Comment: and was hoping you could have a look at the code in the edit above